# Where can I find a list of x86_64 assembly instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, instruction-set

[Here](http://home.myfairpoint.net/fbkotler/nasmdocc.html) is a link to a complete (I think) list of NASM instructions, which I presume also covers the x64 bit instruction set for Intel processors.

However, I was hoping there would be a complete list of instructions somewhere, and just that, without the verbosity of an explanation for each one.

Does such a thing exist? It would be useful to have for learning commands (you can guess most of their meanings and google the ones you cant guess), bumping your memory when you cant remember one and scanning for an appropriate command to fill a requirement you have.

Comment: Here is a list of all the instructions http://ref.x86asm.net/ . It will take you a good time to learn all, x86 is CISC which means it has a pretty big instruction set.

Comment: Wow, there's so many! Cool! http://ref.x86asm.net/coder-abc.html

Comment: @snf If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of all the instructions: http://ref.x86asm.net

As x86(_64) is a CISC processor, it has a big instruction set, but the compilers, unless you are optimizing, only use a "small" subset of it. You can check that disassembling binaries with objdump or your preferred disassembler.

Comment: Where can i find that small subset of instructions online? Very helpful if you add it here.

Comment: More precisely http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html (I can use ctrl+F here)